# If my article submission is rejected while my PhD thesis is being examined, do I have to tell the examiners?

Tags: phd, thesis-committee, paper-submission

Because I submitted two journals, and my scholarship just about to end which I have just finished and approved by my supervisors.

So, yep. I wonder if it is necessary to tell the examiners of the thesis, about the progress of my journal submission, while the thesis is under their revision.

As I learned throughout this journey, good news about article submission is always on the borderline for me.  So, the news is not necessarily a good one, and I don't know how much the news will impact the examiners'  decision about my thesis.

Comment: It might help to know what structure your thesis-committee is: are they all/mostly at your institution, sort of like a team of supervisors, or are they at other institutions? In the first case, they may be able to provide advice/edits that help you publish (assuming the thesis contents overlap with the submission), or at least moral support.

Comment: They all from other institutions. However, they can come from anywhere in the world. All I know was the university actually encourages to have the global examiners, rather than the local one, and I don't know who they are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The acceptance of a paper is not something that you are obligated to raise to the members of your thesis committee, because it is not a part of the evaluation of the thesis—it has to be considered on its own merits.

That said, if you are asked about or choose to inform them of the status of the manuscripts, you should not lie about its status.